# Performing Manipulations in sqlserver

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I am working on C# where i have to retrieve data from SQLServer(my database).

The problem i am facing is:
I have a record say 'crocin'(medicine name) which is split in different batches

say

```
Batch Nos  | Shelf nos | Available Medicine Quantity
B1         |  S1       |      30
B2         |  S1       |      30
B3         |  S1       |      30
```

(this distribution is done according to their expiry date)

Suppose my customer wants 50 medicines, then how do i retrieve 50 medicines(i.e 30 from B1 and 20 from B2) from `SQLServer`.(i want a help in writing query/procedure,etc for this)

Note: I cannot put all the medicines in one batch ,say B1, because all have to be split according to their expiry dates.

Comment: I think you would build a `view` joining the 3 tables ordering by `expiry date` and then `SELECT TOP 50` from that view

Comment: Is this data coming from one single table?

Comment: I also have to update my database accordingly. will view help for that??

Comment: Where is the `expiry date` stored?

Comment: yes the data is coming from one single table

Comment: in the same table. every new expiry date creates a new batch number

Comment: @user3032171: You will need to run a `cursor` and update values

Comment: thank you.
more suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

This script will go through each batch in order of their expiry and subtract items from them based on how many items you'd like to fetch.

Using your example it would then update Batch B1 to have 0 items, and B2 to have 10, assuming B1 expired before B2.

This is completely untested and I don't know if it's actually what you're trying to achieve but here is my crack at it.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE FetchMedicine
(
    @AmountToFetch int
)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @TableRowOffset int = 0;
    declare @BatchIdPtr int = 0;
    while(@AmountToFetch > 0)
    BEGIN
        set @BatchIdPtr = (Select Id from [Batch] where Quantity > 0 order by [ExpiryDate] OFFSET @TableRowOffset ROW FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY)
        declare @BatchQuantity int = (select top 1 Quantity from [Batch] where Id = BatchIdPtr)

        if(@BatchQuantity > @AmountToFetch)
        BEGIN
            update [Batch] set Quantity = (@BatchQuantity - @AmountToFetch) where Id = @BatchIdPtr
            BREAK;
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            update [Batch] set Quantity = 0 where Id = @BatchIdPtr
            set @AmountToFetch = @AmountToFetch - @BatchQuantity
        END

        set @TableRowOffset = @TableRowOffset + 1
    END
END
```